# How do I track down specifics for an opencart module that is rendering on my site but missing everything except the catalog template file?

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

I've inherited an opencart 1.5.5.1 site and am completely new to the cms. From what I've been able to gather, it was built by a competent developer but then went through a hack-it-up development team, and then on to me.  So, I really don't know what all to expect from it.

I currently have a module that is rendering in the left sidebar and I don't know why it's rendering there.  The only file I can find in the file stack related at all to this "module" is a single template file within the catalog directory structure called:

```
/catalog/view/theme/mytheme/template/module/affiliate_profile_select.tpl
```

All of the other installed modules on the site seem to have lots of other files associated with them, whose locations are verified by the research I've done on creating opencart modules: ie, module files in the following directories:

```
/catalog/controller/module/
/catalog/language/english/module/
/catalog/model/module/
/catalog/view/theme/mytheme/template/module/
/admin/controller/module/
/admin/language/english/module/
/admin/model/module/
/admin/view/template/module/
```

From what I've been able to find though, this single file (affiliate_profile_select.tpl) is the only file in the file stack that is associated with this module.

I can't find anything related to this module, and/or file, inside any of the vqmod php or xml files.

I can't find anything related to this module in the admin area.  I've tried searching through all of the installed modules for other generic identifiers (the section view is rendering at the very top of the left-sidebar on most non-logged-in pages, so I'm looking for layout locations of "Left Sidebar" and positions less than 2), but haven't found anything.

And yet, the section is obviously rendering on the site, so it has to be there somewhere.  In fact, it's rendering in two places.  It's also in the top-content section of the mobile view of the home page.

Right now it's almost feeling like it was a module that had been written, installed, and configured, and then someone deleted all but one of the files associated with the module. Could a situation like that happen?

Is there any way to track this issue down by querying the database? Or would the template inclusion obviously be inside a file somewhere and I just need to find it?  To complicate matters, the hosting company doesn't allow remote login with a console (from what I can tell).  Otherwise I'd just have run a grep for the filename in case someone had just thrown an "include()" statement in somewhere. The only place I've checked for something like that so far was in the left-sidebar template file:

```
/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/column_left.tpl
```

but it's just a simple for-loop that echoes out the module views.

Any help or direction on how I might be able to track this problem down would be of significant help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Opencart, **.tpl** (template) files are always called by controllers which as you probably guessed are in `catalog/controller/`.  An if it's a module (showing in left sidebar position, it's probably going to be in `catalog/controller/module/`. First order of business would be to find the controller that's calling the template you referred to.  I'd probably start by getting into a shell and doing something like this from the site's docroot:

```
grep -r affiliate_profile_select .
```

From there you should be able to find the associated module controller and any other logic involved.  Sometimes people use vQmod to add something on to a pre-existing module so that can possibly explain the lack of other similarly named files.

Comment: So yeah, I realized over the weekend that I could just download the entire catalog directory of the website to my local machine and grep it from there. Grumble. Found the template reference in the affiliate_profile controller file.  Seems to me that this is a poor place to put the render of the actual template file as it mixes the controller and view code.  Is probably the reason why I didn't think to look here in the first place.  Thanks for the help that should have been obvious to me in the first place.  :) Guess I just got too focused on the complicated stuff to see the easy solution.